# Magento 2 Order Status is not changing

Tags: magento2

I created a module that changes the status of the order from pending to processing based on specific payment status and if the payment status doesn't match, it cancel those order. the module is working fine for canceling the orders but not changing the status to processing.
Here's my code

```
protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface
 */
protected $orderManagement;
protected $date;
protected $orderFactory;
/**
 * CancelOrder constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $date,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
) {
    $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
    $this->date = $date;
}

public function execute()
{
    $today          = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    $to             = strtotime('-120 min', strtotime($today));
    $time = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $to);
    //$agoDate = '2016-11-07'; // For example date, your logic to calculate the date here
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
        ->addFilter(
            'updated_at',
            array('from' => $time),
            'lteq'
        )->addFilter(
            'status',
            'pending',
            'eq'
        )->create();

    $orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
    foreach ($orders->getItems() as $order) {
        $payment = $order->getPayment();
        $paymentStatus = $payment->getAdditionalInformation('payment_status');
        if($paymentStatus == 'SETTLED_BY_MERCHANT' || $paymentStatus == 'AUTHORISED') {
            $orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
            $order->setStatus($orderState);
            $this->orderRepository->save($order);
        } 
        else {
            $order->setStatus(Order::STATE_CANCELED);
            $this->orderRepository->save($order); // Cancel Order
            
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know if it works,

```
if($paymentStatus == 'SETTLED_BY_MERCHANT' || $paymentStatus == 'AUTHORISED') {
            $orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
            //set order state before setting status
            $order->setState($orderState);
            $order->setStatus($orderState);
            $this->orderRepository->save($order);
}
```

i just added this line `$order->setState($orderState);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following way

```
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

    $orderId = 1;
    //Use constructor injection for Order class. Below $objectManager is just for testing/explanation purpose
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
    $orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
    $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus($orderState);
    $order->save();
```

set order state in your code.

```
$order->setState($orderState)->setStatus($orderState);
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks !!